# Detect 415 HTTP code while loading an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

The issue is quite simple, I've got a form which targets an iframe. When the form is submitted the load event fires off, so I can use it as a ajax fallback for upload picture functionality for IE8/IE9.

```
$('#iframe').load(function () {
    // do something
});
```

This works ok, however the load event fires off even if I get 415 http code back and no response.

How can I retrieve the HTTP status code from the loaded iframe? A solution that doesn't need any server-side adjustments would be really helpful.

Comment: I don't think it's possible as the request was made by the browser itself, therefore javascript cannot get a handle on it to check the response status. If you load the content yourself via `ajax()` you could then check the response.

Comment: I can't make an ajax call, IE8 doesn't support FormData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't tell success or failure by HTTP Status Code unless you use `ajax` method, however, you can do this:

```
$('#iframe').load(function (e) {
    var $iframe = $("#iframe");

    //there is response
    if($iframe.innerHTML){

    }
    //error happens
    else{

    }
});
```

Comment: Hero of the day. Thanks!